# Entity Framework Core: Multiple One-to-Many Relationships between two Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I try to get a translation model running by having

```cs
public class Item
{
  public Item
  {
      TextTranslationID = Guid.NewGuid();
      DescriptionTranslationID = Guid.NewGuid();

      TextTranslations = new HashSet<Translation>();
      DescriptionTranslations = new HashSet<Translation>();
  }

  [Key]
  public int ItemID { get; set; }

  public Guid TextTranslationID { get; set; }

  public Guid DescriptionTranslationID { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey(nameof(TextTranslationID))]
  public virtual ICollection<Translation> TextTranslations { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey(nameof(DescriptionTranslationID))]
  public virtual ICollection<Translation> DescriptionTranslations { get; set; }
}
```

and the translation entity

```cs
public class Translation
{
  public Translation()
  {
    UniqueTranslationID = Guid.NewGuid();
  }

  [Key]
  public Guid UniqueTranslationID { get; set; }

  /// <summary>
  /// The translation id, keyed with the language.
  /// </summary>
  [Required]
  public Guid TranslationID { get; set; }

  /// <summary>
  /// The 2-char language code. eg "en", "es"
  /// </summary>
  [Required]
  [StringLength(2, MinimumLength = 2)]
  public string Language { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [StringLength(2000)]
  public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

This is a single-direction relationship so I don't need nor want an Translation.Parent or something similar on the Translation entity.
The `Item` Entity is just one of many consumers of translation, so an inverse property is not wanted here.
As you can see the Item has two connections to translations.

I already tried so many combinations with the modelbuilder to achieve such a simple task in sql but the generated sql script always wants to add a DescriptionTranslationID and TextTranslationID to the translation table.

```cs
...

migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Translations",
    columns: table => new
    {
        UniqueTranslationID = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
        TranslationID = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
        Language = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(2)", maxLength: 2, nullable: false),
        Text = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(2000)", maxLength: 2000, nullable: false),
        DescriptionTranslationID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true),
        TextTranslationID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true)
    },

...
```

How can I setup the two one-to-many relationships from item to translations?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete example with the solution.
Given two entities (Question, Answer) that needs multiple localizations (Localization) without the need of inverse navigation.

```cs
public class CatalogQuestion
{
  public CatalogQuestion()
  {
    TextTranslationID = Guid.NewGuid();
    DescriptionTranslationID = Guid.NewGuid();

    TextTranslations = new HashSet<Translation>();
    DescriptionTranslations = new HashSet<Translation>();
  }

  [Key]
  public int CatalogQuestionID { get; set; }
  public Guid TextTranslationID { get; set; }
  public Guid DescriptionTranslationID { get; set; }

  ///

  public virtual ICollection<Translation> TextTranslations { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Translation> DescriptionTranslations { get; set; }
}

public class CatalogAnswer
{
  public CatalogAnswer()
  {
    TextTranslationID = Guid.NewGuid();
    DescriptionTranslationID = Guid.NewGuid();

    TextTranslations = new HashSet<Translation>();
    DescriptionTranslations = new HashSet<Translation>();
  }

  [Key]
  public int CatalogAnswerID { get; set; }
  public Guid TextTranslationID { get; set; }
  public Guid DescriptionTranslationID { get; set; }
  
  ///

  public virtual ICollection<Translation> TextTranslations { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Translation> DescriptionTranslations { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Allows every entity that has a <see cref="Guid"/> to have a translation.
/// </summary>
public class Translation
{
  public Translation()
  {
    UniqueTranslationID = Guid.NewGuid();
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Used for direct addressing this single translation.
  /// </summary>
  [Key]
  public Guid UniqueTranslationID { get; set; }

  /// <summary>
  /// The translation id, keyed with the language.
  /// Must not be an empty guid.
  /// </summary>
  [Required]
  public Guid TranslationID { get; set; }

  /// <summary>
  /// The 2-char language code. eg "de", "en"
  /// </summary>
  [Required]
  [StringLength(2, MinimumLength = 2)]
  public string Language { get; set; }
  
  [Required]
  [StringLength(2000)]
  public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

This is the FluentApi for the modelbuilder that glues the stuff together:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Translation>(entity => {
      entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.TranslationID, e.Language }).IsUnique();
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<CatalogQuestion>(entity => {
      entity.HasMany(e => e.TextTranslations).WithOne().HasForeignKey(e => e.TranslationID).HasPrincipalKey(e => e.TextTranslationID).HasConstraintName("FK_Translations_CatalogQuestionsText_TranslationID");
      entity.HasMany(e => e.DescriptionTranslations).WithOne().HasForeignKey(e => e.TranslationID).HasPrincipalKey(e => e.DescriptionTranslationID).HasConstraintName("FK_Translations_CatalogQuestionsDescription_TranslationID");
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<CatalogAnswer>(entity => {
      entity.HasMany(e => e.TextTranslations).WithOne().HasForeignKey(e => e.TranslationID).HasPrincipalKey(e => e.TextTranslationID).HasConstraintName("FK_Translations_CatalogAnswersText_TranslationID");
      entity.HasMany(e => e.DescriptionTranslations).WithOne().HasForeignKey(e => e.TranslationID).HasPrincipalKey(e => e.DescriptionTranslationID).HasConstraintName("FK_Translations_CatalogAnswersDescription_TranslationID");
    });
}
```

Since we're creating a relationship between two non-pripary-keys we need to define it in the FlientApi, otherwise the migration will be confused with annotations and FluentApi.